De que manera puedo cambiar el tamaño de un texto determinado que se imprime en la consola en c++?
estoy intentando cambiar el tamaño de un solo texto en c++ sin que esto modifique otros textos que se encuentran en mi programa pero no encuentro maneras de realizarlo sin que cambie el tamaño de todos los textos de mi programa. Estoy utilizando el siguiente codigo para ello:
static CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX  fontex;
fontex.cbSize = sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX);
HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hOut, 0, &fontex);
fontex.FontWeight = 700; //GROSOR
fontex.dwFontSize.X = 36; //ALTURA
fontex.dwFontSize.Y = 36; //ANCHO
SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hOut, 0 , &fontex);

Lo que sucede es que esto no me permite seleccionar un solo texto sino que cambia todo el texto que se encuentra abajo de este codigo.

Los programas de consola no tienen noción de tipografías. Solo reciben e imprimen texto sin formato.
Si bien cada sistema operativo tiene la posibilidad de exponer una API para modificar diferentes aspectos de la consola, no es posible cambiar la tipografía de una parte en específico del texto. Si lo fuera ya existiría algún programa que aproveche la funcionalidad.
Si necesitas poder mostrar diferentes tipografías, mejor planteate si realmente quieres usar CLI y no una GUI. Las interfaces gráficas te permiten un control más fino de lo que muestran.
